# Requiring inherited properties using DataAnnotations

Tags: .net, vb.net, inheritance, data-annotations

I have code similar to the following:

```
Imports System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations
Class Person
    Dim _ssn As String = ""
    Public Overridable Property SSN(format As Boolean) As String
    Get
        If format Then
            ' Return formatted SSN
        Else : Return _ssn
        End If
    End Get
    Set(value As String)
        _ssn = value
    End Set
    End Property
End Class

Class Employee
    Inherits Person

    <Required()>
    Public Overrides Property SSN(format As Boolean) As String
    Get
        Return MyBase.SSN(format)
    End Get
    Set(value As String)
        MyBase.SSN(format) = value
    End Set
End Property
End Class
```

When I use Validator.ValidateObject() on the Employee class, it validates just fine even though the SSN property is Nothing.

Any ideas why the required attribute isn't working?

Thanks

Comment: `Dim e = New Employee()` `Validator.ValidateObject(e, New ValidationContext(e))` results in `ValidationException: The SocialSecurityNumber field is required.` for me.

Comment: Hmm, that's strange. I just created a new project with my example in it and it works for me, too. I'm going to investigate a bit more to see what in my actual project is causing this to not work.

Comment: Okay, I discovered what's missing that is causing the behavior described. The social security number property is actually a parameterized property. I'll update it in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that validation is not going to work on an indexed/parameterized property, since I don't see how the validator could work out what to pass in for your `format` parameter.  As a workaround, you could create a non-indexed property to put the `Required` attribute on.

```
Class Employee
    Inherits Person

    <Required()>
    Public Overloads Property SSN As String
        Get
            Return Me.SSN(False)
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            Me.SSN(False) = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Overrides Property SSN(format As Boolean) As String
        Get
            Return MyBase.SSN(format)
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            MyBase.SSN(format) = value
        End Set
    End Property

End Class
```

To be honest, I would probably change the design to have two properties - a read/write `SSN` property, and a read-only `FormattedSSN` property, which seems cleaner to me (but maybe that's just me!).

Comment: Great minds think alike apparently. We just posted the same solution. :)

Comment: Ha, we must type at the same speed too, to post within 30 seconds of each other! :-)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like parameterized properties just won't take the required attribute. As a workaround, I used overloads to solve this.

```
Imports System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations

Class Person

    Dim _ssn As String
    Public Property SSN() As String
        Get
            Return _ssn
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            _ssn = JustNumbers(value)
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property SSN(format As String) As String
        Get
            Try
                Return CInt(Me.SSN).ToString(format)
            Catch ex As InvalidCastException : Return Me.SSN
            End Try
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            SSN = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Function IsValid() As Boolean
        Return Validator.TryValidateObject(Me, New ValidationContext(Me), Nothing)
    End Function
End Class

Class Employee
    Inherits Person

    <Required()>
    Public Overloads Property SSN() As String
        Get
            Return MyBase.SSN
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            MyBase.SSN = value
        End Set
    End Property
End Class
```